# Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

when I send user log in endpoint from postman I was given this Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access response from my intelij IDE what is the causes and how can I resolve it

I try to hit logging endpoint from postman

Comment: can you share your code please ?